In Spring Framework tests, how to make PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer search System Properties first?
I am not using Spring Boot. I have a plain Spring Framework application.
I have a Spring integration test written with SpringJUnitConfig.
I am using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.
By default Spring Environment properties are searched last with PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.
How can I use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in tests and make it search Java System Properties before all other properties?
As described in the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer's Javadoc, one needs to manipulate the Environment before the test is executed. But how can I do this?

There is a localOverride property on PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer you could try to switch to see if it makes a difference. But I don't really understand by reading the javadocs what local in this context means to give a specific answer.

@SpaceTrucker localOverride refers to the properties object in PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer itself.

You probably don't want to change the order, but use @TestPropertySource instead. These have a higher precedence than system properties.
See Context Configuration with Test Property Sources for how to do that without Spring Boot.
